# First use of -nomics after a name

Tags: etymology, portmanteau-words

Several people have had -nomics added to their name to indicate their economic policies. For example, [Rogernomics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogernomics) and [Abenomics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abenomics) .

To whom was the first -nomics attached? Was it Ronald Reagan?

Wiktionary's entry on [-nomics](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-nomics) mentions that it's related to economics, and provides etymological information on that, but not on when it first got attached to people.

Comment: I don't offhand recall any such term prior to *Reaganomics*, in part, I suspect, because the construction only works with some names.

Comment: (However, I am vaguely recalling something similar hung on Wilson, or, more likely, Hoover.  And, of course, after Reagan, the construction was force-fit onto Bill Clinton and at least one of the Bushes, though not with nearly the popularity of *Reaganomics*.)

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, the first U.S. President to receive the Surnamenomics treatment was [Richard Nixon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixonomics). A Google Books search finds mentions of Nixonomics going back to 1971. Martin Bronfenbrenner devoted an entire academic paper to "[Nixonomics and Stagflation Reconsidered](https://books.google.com/books?id=-wZRIuTrwYEC&q=%22nixonomics%22&dq=%22nixonomics%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwA2oVChMI1tiak6qiyAIVBZWICh39nwW9)," in *Michigan Business Papers*, issue 57 (1971).

The possibility that Nixon was the first person of any public notoriety to have *-nomics* suffixed to his name is greatly increased, in my opinion, by the unusual suitability of the name *Nixon* to portmanteauing with *economics*. For one thing, the *x* sound in *Nixon* and the *x* sound in *economics* make a catchy pairing—but even better, the two words share an *-on-* term that effectively allows the first syllable *Nix-* in *Nixon* to replace the first syllable *ec-* in *economics*. This is the kind of fortuity that journalists (and business professors) can't resist exploiting. *Keynesonomics* and *Marxonomics* (for example) don't have the same cachet.

Answer (score 1):

**Research is ongoing:** so far I've uncovered a February, 1970 reference to Nixonomics, which is undoubtedly a predecessor to Reaganonomics:

*TIME*, "[Business: The Rising Attack on Nixonomics](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,878183,00.html)" ...

**Later, after having exhausted the resources available to a lazy man:** Although a [source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nixonomics) on the web claims that the term 'Nixonomics' was coined by Walter Heller for an eponymous speech given in October, 1969, William Safire stopped just short of suggesting in a 1982 *New York Times* article that he coined the term himself:

> In the summer of 1969, I wrote a memorandum for my White House colleagues using the term Nixonomics to hail the ingenious replacement of the Democrats' ''new economics.'' About that time, columnists Evans and Novak were the first to use Nixonomics in print. Walter Heller, a father of the ''new economics,'' was quoted in Time magazine in November 1969, using Nixonomics disparagingly. Since that time, the term I used with such high hopes has fallen on hard times.

(From *The New York Times*, "[ON LANGUAGE; THAT ICY TINGLE](http://www.nytimes.com/1982/11/07/magazine/on-language-that-icy-tingle.html)", By William Safire, November 7, 1982.)

Ten years later, in 1992, Safire backpedalled from his earlier suggestion by rather vaguely attributing the first uses of 'Nixonomics' to "some of us". He then parenthetically suggested that Nixon was the first to acquire the tag. Although Safire reasoned the suffix would've fit with Johnson also, because of the terminal en, he declared the suffix wasn't used for Johnson:

> For the omics suffix to work, the President's name must end in an n. This all began when some of us in 1969 began pushing Nixonomics. (Although Johnsonomics would have been an effective neologism, it was not used, suggesting that Nixonomics was the form's first Presidential use.)

(From *The New York Times*, "[ON LANGUAGE; Retronym Watch](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/11/01/magazine/on-language-retronym-watch.html)", by William Safire, November 1, 1992.)

**Beyond and before presidential monickers:** I speculate that the rather lax but simultaneously frenetic atmosphere of the late 1960s contributed to the coinage and acceptance of 'Nixonomics', which then spawned a plethora of similar coinages predicated on 'economics'. However, the suffix '-nomics' is a more general combinative form denoting

> ...the science or study of a subject specified by the first element.

(From the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/259108?redirectedFrom=-nomics#eid).)

In the more rigorous 1950s and before, I doubt such coinages would've met with general acceptance. However, I continued the search, looking for coinages based on economic luminaries such as Adam Smith and Karl Marx. Those searches were not productive.

Comment: Have you tried "Hitlernomics"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, no, I didn't think to try that one. At your suggestion, I looked around--it seems to be a very recent coinage. If Safire is right (which is moot), the names suited to the -nomics neologisms would be likely to end in en, and of course Hitler doesn't qualify. 'Arayanomics' I also ran across while looking for 'Hitlernomics', but it seemed to be an even more recent coinage than the latter.